# How to predict data in an input field with spring boot as user type?

Tags: spring-boot

Can anyone please help me out on this issue?

I would like to predict words from a database into an input field using spring boot. Example if I type `«` I am searching for a book called `snowfall »` in the input field, the title snowfall should be predicted in this field when the user starts to type the word if it exists in the database.

Many thanks in advance for your answers.

Please see below the content of my html file, and java files:

**index.html:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Books</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="text-center">
        <div>
            <img th:src="@{/images/index.PNG}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="h-100 row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h2>Find a Book</h2>
                    <form method="post">
    
                        <div class="form-group" id="owner">
    
                        </div>
    
    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a href="/books/showPage_Books">Books List</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center">
    
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value = "Search">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
    
        </div>
        <div id='owner1' style='margin:0 auto;width:100%;'></div>
        <div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Book Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Author</th>
                    <th scope="col">Book Reference</th>
    
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
    
                <tr >
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    
        <!--<script th:src="@{/search/js/source1.js}"></script>-->
        <script src="source1.js"></script>
    
        <script>
            var owner = document.getElementById('owner');
            var p = completely(owner, {
                fontSize:'32px',
                promptInnerHTML:''
            });
            p.input.style.borderTop =    '2px solid #999';
            p.input.style.borderBottom = '2px solid #999';
            p.onChange = function (text) {
                p.startFrom = text.lastIndexOf(' ')+1;
                p.repaint();
            };
            p.options = ["snowvfall","Romeo & Juliet","C++"];
    
            p.input.maxLength = 50; // limit the max number of characters in the input text
        </script>
        <script>
            var selectedOptionText = $('#owner').find(":selected").text();
             $("p").text(selectedOptionText);
    
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Books.java:**

```
    package com.progweb.Progweb.Models;
    
    import javax.persistence.*;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "books")
    public class Books {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id;
    
        @Column(name="bookName", length=100, nullable=false, unique=false)
        private String bookName;
    
        @Column(name="bookRef", length=100, nullable=false, unique=false)
        private String bookRef;
    
        @Column(name="bookAuthor", length=100, nullable=false, unique=false)
        private String bookAuthor;
    
    }
    
    BookController.java:
    
    package com.progweb.Progweb.Controllers;
    
    import com.progweb.Progweb.Models.Books;
    import com.progweb.Progweb.Repository.BooksRepository;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(path="/books")
    public clas`enter code here`s BookController {
        @Autowired
        private BooksRepository booksRepository;
    
        @GetMa`enter code here`pping("/index")
        public String index () {
            return "index";
        }
    
        //Affichage de la page books
        @GetMapping("/showPage_Books")
        public String ShowPage_Books(Model model, RedirectAttributes attributes){
            List<Books> books = new ArrayList<Books>();`enter code here`
            books = booksRepository.allBooks();
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("books",books);
            //model.addAttribute("books", books);
            return "Page_Books";
        }
    }
    
    BooksRepository.java:
    
    package com.progweb.Progweb.Repository;
    
    import com.progweb.Progweb.Models.Books;
    
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Repository
    public interface BooksRepository extends CrudRepository<Books, Integer> {
        @Query(value = "select * from books",nativeQuery = true)
        public List<Books> allBooks();
    }
```

**my pom.xmlfile:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.progweb</groupId>
        <artifactId>Progweb</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>Progweb</name>
        <description>School project</description>
    
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
        </dependencies>
    
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

if im following your requirement , when the UI user inserts for example "a" you would like to show a list of all books starting (or containing a), this is called a LIKE query - using the `@Query` annotation you are already using in your repo you should do this (this will return everything that contains 'a'):

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM books b WHERE b.bookName LIKE %:title%")
List<Book> searchByTitleLike(@Param("title") String title);
```

for everything starting with 'a':

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM books b WHERE b.bookName LIKE :title%")
List<Book> searchByTitleLike(@Param("title") String title);
```

this is an altered example taken from this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-like-queries

Comment: Hello asafb,
Thanks for your answer. Yes it is some thing like that I want to do. I want to be able to predict the word in the input field regardless at which position the word is typed (begining, middle or at the end). And to also whhen I click on the search button I should be able to get the details of the book based on the keyword predicted. With the link you added in your comment  I could only query the db but can't predict in the input search field. Do you have an idea how I could do that?

Comment: the correct way of doing so would be to expose an api that fetches the book list , this api can also receive the input from the user and call the relevant service (as mentioned above) this will return a filtered list which will be presented by the UI

Comment: Hello asafb,
So I created a book repository class(please see below) with two queires. The first query fetches all the books in the database and the second fetches a book regarding the string passed in parameter.
Sorry my indentation is kind of poor on stack overflow because I'm new here and I don't know how to well indent my code in the input field

Comment: import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface BooksRepository extends CrudRepository<Books, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "select * from books",nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Books> allBooks();

    @Query(value = "select * from books where bookName like ?1",nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Books> getAbook(String bookName);
}

Comment: Please also see below the two methods I define in my controller class

Comment: `@GetMapping("/showPage_Books")
    public String ShowPage_Books(Model model, RedirectAttributes attributes){
        List<Books> books = new ArrayList<Books>();
        books = booksRepository.allBooks();
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("books",books);
        //model.addAttribute("books", books);
        //return "Page_Books";
        //String jsonStrAll = JSONArray.toJSONString(books);
        //return jsonStrAll;
        return books.toString();
    }`

Comment: `@GetMapping("/fetch_Book/{bookName}")
    public String fetch_Book(Model model, RedirectAttributes attributes, String bookName){
        List<Books> book = new ArrayList<Books>();
        book = booksRepository.getAbook(bookName);
        //attributes.addFlashAttribute("books",book);
        //return "index";
        String jsonStr = JSONArray.toJSONString(book);
        return jsonStr;
    }`

Comment: Do you have any advice please?

Comment: Hello can anyone please advice on my above comments?
Many thanks in advance